# Relative Layout does not scroll after adding scrollview

Tags: android, android-layout

Good day. I have a layout code shown below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/app_bar" />


        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="165dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/viewpager"
            android:background="#33000000">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_image_description"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:text="Shop Name"
                android:textColor="#FFF" />


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_point_group"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingRight="10dp">

            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>


        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/cardList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout" />


    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I have connected my recyclerview with a list of data but why is RecyclerView Layout is scrollable but not the entire Relativelayout. I have wrapped the RelativeLayout with ScrollView. it seems like not working. please see the image below  [image: This is how to layout look like]

Do let me know if you guys have better solution for this. Billion thanks.

Comment: you have set `fill_parent` for Relative as well as ScrollView

Comment: @user10908....Please try my below code

Comment: Try to add this properties : 
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" RelativeLayout

Comment: **Never** use `fill_parent`, it's been deprecated for ages! Use `match_parent` instead. And as for the cause of the error: the height of the `RelativeLayout` in your `ScrollView` has to be at to `wrap_content`. Naturally there can be no scrolling of both the `RelativeLayout` and `ScrollView` have the same size, by using `wrap_content` the height of the `RelativeLayout` will grow with its children and one of gets bigger than the `ScrollView` you will be able to scroll.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `RelativeLayout` height to wrap_content

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
```

Answer (score 1):

You have added one scrolling component in another- RecycleView in a Scrollview
So only one will take focus. This is against android guidelines. you should never put one scrolling component in another.
However to achieve both scrolling

```
yourRecycleView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    // Setting on Touch Listener for handling the touch inside ScrollView
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // Disallow the touch request for parent scroll on touch of child view
    v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
    return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: There is a rule on stackoverflow that you should post a comment on why you downvoted my answer

Comment: There is no such rule here.

Comment: It is suggested that atleast give a suitable explaination for downvoting so that i'l' get to know what i did wrong, not just for the sake of it that you have permission to downvote